# What is Wannier state in solid-state physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I only retrieved information about the Wannier function, but I still don't know exactly what the Wannier state is.
I would appreciate it if someone could explain it.

Comment: Have you tried @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function  ?  and @ https://chempedia.info/info/wannier_states/  .

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you don't understand, else it is hard to help you. Do you know what Bloch states are? Do you 'understand' the definition of Wannier states in terms of Bloch functions? Is there something specific you want to know?

Comment: Thank you, this link https://chempedia.info/info/wannier_states/ is useful.